# .htaccess to redirect all URLs to index.php except for files and directories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm redirecting all files, urls, directories to index.php, There is a routing system.

But i want if there is a php file for example "browse.php?id=1", i dont want redirect to index.php this file. How can i do that? .php files should not go index.php

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Isn't that already the case? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is a condition to only rewrite if there is no "real file".

Comment: but i have a browse.php and it is going index.php :/